# Get path to theme assets in Twig template

Tags: media, 8, theming

I have a question about getting a path to an image in a Twig template. The image is not assigned to a field or something. Just a static image which is stored in "MYTHEME/image/icon/my-icon.png".

In Drupal 7 I get the path in my node.template with the following code:

```
<img src="<?php print base_path() . path_to_theme(); ?>/image/icons">/my-icon.png
```

How does it work with in Drupal 8? I tried to pass a variable in `template_preprocess_node()`.

**MYTHEME.theme:**

```
$variables['images_path'] = \Drupal::theme()->getActiveTheme()->getPath() . '/image/';
```

**Twig template:**

```
<img src="{{ images_path  ~ 'icons/' ~ 'my-icon.png' }}">
```

It doesn't work. There is no PHP error, but the path is wrongly said to be http://localhost/node/themes/template/image/icons/my-icon.png.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

you can use `{{ base_path ~ directory }}` which will fix the absolute problem, no need to do any preprocessing, both of these variables are included by core.

For example

```
<img src="{{ base_path ~ directory }}/images/logo.png" alt="My Logo" />
```

*PS. the `~` helper in twig is concatenate.*

Edit: at least in the page*.html.twig templates base_path variable is included, possibly you will need to do preprocessing for other templates, you can easily check with `{{ dump() }}` if the variables are present

```
// File: THEMENAME.theme in your theme's root directory
function THEMENAME_preprocess(&$variables, $hook)
{
    $variables['base_path'] = base_path();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. One quick comment: I had to explicitly add $variables['base_path'] = base_path(); to my THEME_preprocess_html theme hook to make it available to the html.html.twig template file.

Comment: Be careful about using `{{ directory }}` Twig variable in a theme that you intend to use as a base theme and create sub-themes for:  https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/277278

Comment: The [twig template suggestions](https://www.drupal.org/project/twigsuggest) module provides `{{ base_bath }}` to every template; otherwise for some templates you'll have to do as Marcos Buarque did in the above comment, or Matoeil did in https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/238535/4195

Comment: And no one taught that naming this "theme_directory" would have been better than "directory"?

Answer (score 18):

```
<img src="/{{ directory }}/images/logo.png"/>
```

worked for me when

```
<img src="{{ base_path ~ directory }}/images/logo.png" alt="My Logo" />
```

did not

for content template, i had to use in .module

```
   function hook_preprocess(&$variables, $hook) {

  $module_handler = Drupal::service('module_handler');
  $path = $module_handler->getModule('myModuleName')->getPath();

  if(isset($variables['region']) && $variables['region'] == 'content'){
    $variables['module_path'] = $path;
    $variables['http_host'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
```

and

```
  <img src="{{ module_path }}/images/error404.png" />
  <img src="//{{ http_host }}/{{ module_path }}/images/error403.png" />
```

Comment: This answer should be marked as correct instead

Answer (score 11):

There is by default a `{{ directory }}` variable that you can use that points to your theme directory. The problem is, it's not absolute, just like the one you added. I think that's a bug in core because it should include the base path, but changing that would of course break existing sites that use it.

So you need to add a / in front of it; this would break if Drupal is installed in a subfolder. You can either hardcode that in your template or keep using `base_path()` as you did in 7.x in a custom variable.

Comment: How to use image from `/sites/default/files/MyFolder` ? I have a image MyImage.jpg in MyFolder. Now, in twig template if i wrote `<img src={{ url }} alt={{ text }}>` Here url variable has the path /MyFolder/MyImage.jpg but, it is not working.

Comment: As Berdir wrote: one can simply use `<img src="/{{ directory }}/path/to/image"/>` to get an absolute path.

Answer (score 5):

To print an image url that is inside your custom theme use the following construction:

```
{% set icon_path = [
  url('<front>')|render|trim('/', 'right'),
  active_theme_path(),
  'relative/path/to/image.png'
]|join('/') %}

<img src="{{ icon_path }}" alt="uncategorized"/>
```

If you have already installed twig_tweak module then you can reuse `drupal_url` function:

```
<img src="{{ drupal_url(active_theme_path() ~ '/relative/path/to/image.png', {absolute: true}) }}" alt="uncategorized"/>
```

Comment: This is the most up to date and complete response.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="{{ base_path ~ '/modules/custom/YOUR_MODULE_NAME/images/logo.png' }}" />
```

The above line works for loading images in Twig template where both are placed in your custom module without any need to add $base_path to hook_preprocess.

Comment: Used on Drupal 9.4