# Using images in custom module (not through css)

Tags: 8, media

I am making a flex slider module, and it needs to just load some images statically, the only way I was able to get hold of any of the images was when I used a relative path in a background-image: url(relative-path-to-image) in a css file, but I am not interested in loading it through css.

If I try to access it relative from the template, using `<img src="relative-path-to-image">` it won't work of course, because the `src` tag are being loaded on the client. I have looked a bit at the templating system and I can use a {{ directory }}  variable inside of twig, to maybe get the absolute path to the images right. But I just feel like even if I made that work it would still be a disaster implementation.

So my question is, if you need to add a  tag and give it a src path-to-image, what is your go-to solution to get that image accessible?

Comment: Where are those images located?

Comment: In the root of the module, in a images folder

Comment: in your preprocess function set the path to the image as $variables['your variable'] = drupal_get_path('module', 'name of module') . '/images/image1.jpg';

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to access images in the module folder:

preprocess function (assuming page, but can be any other template):

```
mymodule.module:
function mymodule_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  global $base_root, $base_path;
  $variables['image1'] = $base_root . $base_path . drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/images/' . $image1;
}
```

twig:

```
<img src="{{ image1 }}" />
```

I don't know your logic for multiple images, I guess you have to code a loop for this.

But accessing static images in a module folder is not a cms way to do this, I would put the images into a node. You can make a content type "slider" for this and then access the absolute path of the image field:

twig:

```
<img src="{{ file_url(slider_node.field_slider_image.0.entity.uri.value) }}" />
```

Here you can code a twig loop to access multiple images in the field.

Comment: omg, this was exactly what i was looking at, looking at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/184148/get-path-to-image-src-from-twig-template .... But i still wasn't 100% sure how to go about it, Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Instead of hardcoding $base_root and $base_path, just use ? `file_create_url(drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/images/' . $image1)`