# How can get path of image (src) in twig template of a module?

Tags: 8, media

How can I get access to image path (source/url) in twig template of a module?
I try to render an image that's located in my module folder in module template, this image is a static image that's not assigned to a field.
I try several methods to achieve this demands for eg:

```
<img src="{{ directory }}/image/icons/my-image.svg" />
```

and below method:

**MyModule.module**

```
function MyModule_preprocess(&$variables, $hook) {
    $variables['base_path'] = base_path();
}
```

and then in template:

```
<img src="{{ base_path ~ directory }}image/icons/my-image.svg" />
```

And i try solution that's written in this article too: [Using images in custom module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/184329/using-images-in-custom-module-not-through-css?rq=1)
But both of them refer to my theme directory instead of module directory and seems none of them work in module template.
Thanks for any solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `file_create_url` much like Drupal 7 to transform a file path to file url. To get the path to the module, you should use `drupal_get_path`, combined it could look like this:

```
function my_module_preprocess(&$variables, $hook) {
  $variables['img_path'] = file_create_url(drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module') . '/image/icons/my-image.svg');
}
```

Comment: So in twig, you can use `<img src="{{ img_path }}" />`