# How to use variable value in twig file?

Tags: 8, theming

I have below code in:

```
{% set img_url = item.image.url ? item.image.url : {{ base_path ~ directory }}'/images/default.png' %}
```

Twig file. How to make it work so it will take full default image path?

Comment: check this one https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/184148/get-path-to-image-src-from-twig-template

Answer (score 1):

To get the `base_url` (path) you will need this in your `THEMENAME.theme` file

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  global $base_url;
  $variables['base_path'] = $base_url;
}
```

Then it will be available in your twig template

But most of the times you will not need the full path to display an image

You can try the following

```
{% set img_url = item.image.url ? item.image.url : '/'{{ directory }}'/images/default.png' %}
```

Comment: You can use Drupal's `base_path()` function, to get a relative path to the drupal web. `$GLOBALS['base_url']` does return the absolute url. Just using `{{ '/' ~ directory }}` does not work if your drupal website is installed in a subfolder of webroot (e.g. example.com/mydrupalproject/).