# How can I get the module path in twig?

Tags: 8, theming

I have a module and created twig templates there. I just followed the documentation here: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/create-custom-twig-templates-for-custom-module

I want to include a JS file from the twig. And the JS file is located inside the module folder. I have this code in the twig:

```
<script src="/{{ directory }}/js/script.js"></script>
```

But the `directory` is returning the theme path NOT the module path. How can I get the module path inside the twig?

Comment: The Drupal 8 way is to define a library and then attach the library with `{{ attach_library('module-name/library-name') }}` [read the docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme) for more info.

Comment: @Jdrupal, this is not a duplicate because I am asking how to get the module path from the twig file. NOT php

Comment: As @NoSssweat says the correct way is to create a library and attach it in twig.

Comment: @aceraven777 The principle is the same as in the duplicate; the variable you need isn’t available, you have to implement a preprocess hook and make it available via PHP. But as others have said, this is what libraries are for, you shouldn’t need to build a path to an asset yourself

Comment: See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/238535/15055 for `<img src="{{ module_path }}/images/error404.png" />`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get path to image (src) from twig template](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/184148/get-path-to-image-src-from-twig-template)

Comment: @leymannx, your comment helps. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is a solution that can work for your problem without going into php and this solution will work only in case if twig template is under module directory.

Suppose my module structure is like below:

- modules

  - custom_module

    - templates

      - my-template.html.twig
    - js

      - script.js

To include **script.js** in **my-template.html.twig** file. Use below code in **twig** file -

```
{% set module_path = _self|split('/templates') %}
<script src="/{{ module_path[0] }}/js/script.js"></script>
```

In above script `_self` returns the path upto twig file and `split('/templates')` splits the string from `/templates` AND

```
module_path[0] = /modules/custom_module/ 
module_path[1] = /my-template.html.twig
```

However, this is not the appropriate way. This is only a solution for your problem. Appropriate way is to set module path in a variable in preprocess hook and use that variable in twig.