# How can I render a responsive image style from an image in the theme directory?

Tags: 8, theming, media

I am working on template `views-view-fields--myview.html.twig`. But I do 
not think it matters what template you are working with for this to 
work.

I found this Twig that can add Drupal responsive images to an 
image that is not in a field. In this case this image is in the files 
directory. My question is that I want to place this image in my themes 
directory in: `/themes/custom/mytheme/img/mygraphic.png`. What URI can I 
use to make that work in this example?

Second question is: The 
image alt tag is empty even though I provided one. How can I display an 
alt tag?

```
{% set responsiveimagestyle = {
    '#theme': 'responsive_image',
    '#responsive_image_style_id': 'my_custom_responsive_style',
    '#uri': 'public://mygraphic.png',
    '#alt': 'my alt text',
    '#attributes': { class: 'img-responsive' },
} %}
```

In the views-view-fields--myview.html.twig template I now can use the following 
variable.

```
{{ responsiveimagestyle }}
```

The image is wrapped in the picture tag and is using the Drupal Responsive Images style.

Comment: Wouldn’t alt be an attribute?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get path to theme assets in Twig template](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/184148/get-path-to-theme-assets-in-twig-template)

Comment: use https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak  and {{ responsiveimagestyle.alt }}

Comment: @Naveen. I tried this and it did not work

Answer (score 2):

> This is the same when using the image filters from the Twig Tweak
>   module: You can't render responsive images from a random URI, it has
>   to be an URI that is stored in the file_managed DB table. **But with
>   Twig tweak you can render normal image styles from random URIs**, and
>   manually create a responsive image tag by rendering multiple normal
>   image styles. – [Hudri](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/72678/hudri)

Great, so there is a workaround one can do, manually create one:

```
{% set imagePath = '/themes/custom/mytheme/img/mygraphic.png' %}
<img srcset="{{ imagePath|image_style('thumbnail') }} 300w, {{ imagePath|image_style('medium') }} 800w" src="{{ file_url(imagePath) }}" alt="some graphic image" typeof="foaf:Image"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure (though not a 100%) that rendering a responsive image where the original image comes from a theme asset won't work that way. To have a responsive image rendered you need multiple different image derivatives in different sizes. These normally get created automatically during image upload via an image field. I can't imagine that this happens on the fly from an unmanaged image.

Your best bet I guess is to provide a managed image from a theme settings or system settings form. This gets uploaded to the files directory as usual. Maybe all images sizes then get created automatically. Maybe you still need to programmatically ensure the image derivatives get created.

Alternatively you could simply require to upload all necessary image sizes, to then build your own `srcset` from them, see No Sssweat's answer.

The alt tag in your question needs to be added from the `#attributes` array.

Comment: This is the same when using the image filters from the [Twig Tweak module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/twig-tweak/cheat-sheet): You can't render responsive images from a random URI, it has to be an URI that is stored in the `file_managed` DB table. But with Twig tweak you can render normal image styles from random URIs, and manually create a responsive image tag by rendering multiple normal image styles.

Comment: This is image is a default or fallback image for a Paragraph. If an author does not upload an image. It should have a default. And it needs to be a Responsive Image. In my template I first check if the image field has a value, if not then I print the variable {{ responsiveimagestyle }}. This method works and it adds the wrapper picture and source with all the sizes from the custom Responsive preset. They do not want to use the field default image method. I couldn't find a preprocess that could swap out the image.

Comment: The only problem is that I need to place the image in the files directory for this to work. We have multiple load balance servers and instances for dev, preprod and prod. I will need to upload this image to 6 servers. What if the customer wants to change the default image one day? For the alt image I think I can add it using jquery and attach the js directly to this template.

Comment: @Leymannx. Thanks for the tip. You said the alt needs to be added in the attribute array. So I added it there and this works. `'#attributes': { class: 'img-responsive', alt: 'my alt text' }`

Comment: This file is unmanaged and this method does work and use my Responsive Image style. I was surprised. Is there a better way to have a default image appear in a paragraph than this method. Like I mentioned we have multiple servers. I would have to upload the image to all the servers. The customer wanted the image in the themes folder so they can change it in one place.

Comment: I tried an absolute link to the image but I get an error must be a string `'#uri': 'http://mysitedotcom/themes/custom/mytheme/mygraphic.png',`

Comment: @paulcap1 – Provide your own back-end form with image upload to let the client change the image. Store the FID (file ID) in a variable and use that to load the image and apply responsive image styles. As explained by Hudri and in my answer absolute URLs won't work.

Comment: @leymannx Thanks for this. I think that method is better.

Comment: This can be resolved some day.
https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1308152

Answer (score 1):

Might be an old post but you can also do this with the following module https://www.drupal.org/project/system_stream_wrapper

Pass the uri `theme://mytheme/img/mygraphic.png` and the responsive_image theme function should pick up the new theme stream wrapper.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I am able to render the alt text using the following code.

```
{% set card_img = {
   '#theme': 'responsive_image',
   '#responsive_image_style_id': 'concentration_card',
   '#uri':        item.entity.field_ccard_img.entity.field_media_image.entity.fileuri,
   '#attributes': { class: 'card-img', alt: item.entity.field_ccard_img.entity.field_media_image.alt },
                } 
%}
```